# matlab: a tricky vectorization with a function enclosed with 2 nested loops

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I am going through a really hard time vectorizing the below code, unfortunately you need to look over it to understand what is going on.

In gist, this function compares a set of data rows and creates a matrix of comparison relations. The two nested loops calls the inner function (i.e. `compare_weights()`) to compare some particular columns in the data rows. The comparison function returns `0`,`-1` or `1` according to the nested `if-then-else` decisions. So, here goes the main loop --

```
data = rand(4);
disp(data)
[nrow,~] = size(data);
mat = zeros(nrow,nrow);
% fill only the upper triangular of mat
for i = 1:nrow
    for j = i + 1:nrow
        if(i ~= j) 
            % compare_weights() is a function with some nested 
            % if-then-else, that compares the values of 1st,2nd and 
            % 4th columns in data and populates the matrix mat.
            mat(i, j) = ...
                compare_weights(data(i,1:2), data(i,4), ...
                                data(j,1:2), data(j,4));
        end
    end
end
% after the loop, the mat contains the weight comparison relations
% among all the rows in data.
disp(mat)
```

and the inner function `compare_weights()` looks like this --

```
function [ val ] = compare_weights(w1,v1,w2,v2)
%   This function takes the values w1, v1, w2, v2 tuple
%   and does some comparisons, according to the decision
%   this returns -1, 1 or 0.
if(v1 < 0 && v2 < 0)
    if(v1 > v2)
        val = 1 ;
        return ;
    elseif(v1 < v2)
        val = -1 ;
        return ;
    else
        val = 0;
        return ;
    end
else
    if(v1 < 0 && v2 == 0)
        val = -1 ;
        return ;
    elseif(v1 == 0 && v2 < 0)
            val = 1  ;
            return ;
    else
        if(all(w1 > w2))
            val = -1 ;
            return ;
        elseif(all(w1 < w2))
            val = 1 ;
            return ;
        else
            val = 0 ;
            return ;
        end
    end
end
end
```

upon executing the code, you supposed to get this kind of values in `mat` --

```
0    -1    -1     0
0     0    -1     0
0     0     0     1
0     0     0     0
```

when the `data` is --

```
0.5958    0.8310    0.2471    0.5445
0.5004    0.2755    0.4761    0.6410
0.1435    0.1618    0.5691    0.3250
0.9514    0.2711    0.2264    0.1543
```

I have no clue how to vectorize it, even not sure if it's vectorizable at all. Any pointer will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Using `data(row,1:2)` and `data(col,1:2)` in the same code is very confusing since both `row` and `col` refer to ... rows !

Comment: @CrazyRat yes, sorry for that, that `row`/`col` actually refers to the `row`/`col` of the `mat` :-(, it's corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fully [`vectorized approach`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) is certainly possible using [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to cover **`all iterations`** and **`all IF conditional statements`** in one go. Here's one such implementation -

```
%// Collect the relevant column data from input array
n = 2;
d1n = data(:,1:n);
d4 = data(:,4);

%// Logical array corrresponding to starting IF conditional statement
startif = bsxfun(@and,d4<0,d4.'<0)  %//'

%// Create logical arrays of the three IF-ElSE parts
ifelse1 = bsxfun(@gt,d4,d4.') - bsxfun(@lt,d4,d4.')

ifelse2 = -bsxfun(@and,d4<0,d4'==0) + bsxfun(@and,d4==0,d4'<0)

ifelse3 = -all(bsxfun(@gt,permute(d1n,[1 3 2]),permute(d1n,[3 1 2])),3) + ...
            all(bsxfun(@lt,permute(d1n,[1 3 2]),permute(d1n,[3 1 2])),3)

%// Get the output taking care of all the conditionals
out = startif.*ifelse1 + (~startif).*(ifelse2 + (ifelse2==0).*ifelse3)

%// You want to skip the lower triangular elements from input data
out = triu(out)
```

Comment: This is insanely cool, and extremely fast, how do you come up with such vectorization? but still I am having difficulties understanding the whole computation, could you also please add a small explanation after each statement? Is there any guideline to achieve this kind of trick? or this kind of feat only comes from practice?

Comment: one more issue, how do I extend it when `d1..d2` are not exactly two columns, lets say they are `n` columns `d1, d2, ..., dn` ?

Comment: @ramgorur Edited code for that general case! Yeah its all about practice really! Regarding explanation, focus on the Ifelse1/2/3 parts in this vectorized code and match them up the corresponding parts in the original code. Then look for the rest of the If conditionals in the original code and try to imagine how they must come around those if-else parts. That should make it somewhat easier to follow!